# Function like gaussian pdf but bounded $0$ to $1$

Tags: probability, derivatives

I am looking for a differentiable approximation to the equality function.
so for example $f(20,20)$ should be sth like $0.99$ and $f(20,21)$ should be sth like $0.0001 ...$
Generally like a gaussian with a small variance - so with infinite support but with values bounded between $0$ and $1$.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe you are looking for kernels https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)

Comment: thanks @badinmaths ! do you suggest some specific kernel that would meet stated criteria?